# Como melhorar o desempenho da consulta no mongoDB em coleções com milhões de registros e cada uma deles com muitos atributos pesquisáveis?

Tags: mongodb

Há uma coleção com aproximadamente 20 milhões de registros e cada um deles com cerca de 200 atributos pesquisáveis.

Exemplo:

```
{atrib001:"abc", atrib002:"123", atrib003:"1x3"... atrib200:"1zz"}
```

A aplicação que faz pesquisa permite que ela seja montada dinamicamente, de acordo com as opções desejadas pelo usuário.

Como é possível ou qual a recomendação para a criação de índices no mongoDB para melhorar o desempenho desse tipo de pesquisa ? Além disso, é viável criar um índice para cada atributo, que no caso seriam 200 índices, e confiar que o mongoDB escolha o melhor deles ?

Answer (score 1):

(Ressalva: Não sou DBA. E teste qualquer coisa em uma cópia separada do banco antes de aplicar em produção).

No que diz respeito a índices o MongoDB não é tão diferente dos bancos relacionais. São tipicamente árvores-B.

Se a consulta é dinâmica e o usuário pode escolher quais atributos quer incluir na pesquisa, o melhor a fazer é criar os 200 índices, um para cada atributo, e assim as buscas serão otimizadas.

Se houvesse um padrão, por exemplo se o usuário sempre incluísse o atributo 1 e o 2 na pesquisa, você poderia criar um índice composto que mapeasse ambos os atributos de uma vez. Mas como não há, os índices devem ser criados separados.

Answer (score 1):

Olha, pelo conhecimento que tenho em MongoDB, o melhor a ser feito é você analisar a estrutura dos seus objetos, elencar os mais importantes e criar um índice para eles.
Assim como o Piovezan comentou acima, é interessante criar indices compostos.

Além disso o que você pode fazer são consultas com projeção, desta forma você traz somente os dados solicitados, ao invés do objeto inteiro.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/